# Labeling each side of polygon with its length in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, line, arcgis-pro

I am trying to figure out a way in ArcGIS Pro to label each side of a polygon with the length of the side without breaking it into individual polylines.

Comment: Why don't you want to convert the polygons to polylines?

Comment: Polygons don't have length -- they have perimeter.  You *must* split the polygons into polylines to determine the length of border segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as polygon parts between vertices do not have lengths. You will need to use lines.

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured. It seems kind of silly, but I guess I will have to split it into polylines.

Comment: It is really just the polygon structure, it would be cumbersome to make related tables for each line between a vertex and store a separate attribute set for each, that is what polylines do. You could technically do it programmatically (segment A = Vertex A to Vertex B and so on, then add an attribute table for each Segment), then label it, but you essentially then have a polyline structure so why bother.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain whether it is dimension functionality that you are after but according to the [current ArcGIS Pro documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/display-dimensions.htm):

> Creating or editing dimensions is not currently supported in this
>   release of ArcGIS Pro.